# Is 000 (multiple zeros) a valid representation of zero?

Tags: number-systems

I noticed recently that both PHP and Qalculate! (a calculator) accept numbers like 00 or 00000 as meaning 0 (zero). I was curious if these are mathematically valid representations of zero or whether these programs are just sanitzing the input. The Wikipedia entry on zero was no help.

Comment: These are mathematically valid.  Consider that any particular representation of $0$ is still zero: $$0+0=0\cdot 10^n+0\cdot 10^{n-1}+\dots+0\cdot 10^2+0\cdot 10+0=0$$ and this holds for any base other than ten as well.

Comment: Simular as $2.5 = 2.50 = 2.5000....0000$, which is more common in real-life and math situations

Comment: Multiple $0s$ are mathematical valid representation for zero. However, in a lot of programming languages, numeric string begins with zero will be interpreted as an octal number, i.e. a number written in a base of $8$. e.g. $011$ means the decimal number $9$.

Comment: Confirmed, [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) also interpret number string begins with zero as an octal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in most contexts we would consider $00$, $000$, $0000$, etc. to be valid representations of $0$. We could even write $0$ as
$$
\ldots 000
$$
with infinitely many $0$s to the left.

To see why this is OK, consider the question: what is the $1000$s digit of $3$? The answer is **not** that it does not exist. The answer is that the $1000$s digit is $0$.
We just usually don't write the $1000$s digit, because it is more concise to leave off the leading $0$s.
Similarly, the $1$s digit, the $10$s digit, the $100$s digit, and the $1000$s digit of $0$, and so on, are all equal to the digit $0$.